# Is there an IBM Cloud API call to retreive the account name?

Tags: ibm-cloud

The account settings page (Manage > Account > Account Settings) lists an account ID and an account name under the "Account" heading.  The account ID is easy enough to retrieve using the API, but I've not found a way to get the account name.  Is this possible to get using the API?
I've been looking at the [IBM Cloud API Docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs) and at the [Softlayer API docs](https://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client/) but haven't been able to find something which returns the account name.
The ibmcloud CLI returns the info, but I'd rather not have to use the CLI since this will be used from within a Python app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always [use `IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true` on the CLI](https://blog.4loeser.net/2021/01/ibm-cloud-cli-tips-tricks.html) to find out what the `ibmcloud` command is doing. What you see as "account name" is the ID resolved by going to the [user management API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/user-management#get-user-profile).

Comment: Thanks.  The result returned from `get_user_profile` is specific to the user's account.  In this case, I'm wanting to get the info for an account I've been invited to.  Using `IBMCLOUD_TRACE` is great.  It led me to the `/v1/accounts` API call which gets the info I need.